# Unknown update to computer is causing "Cannot open a database created with a previous version" error?

Tags: ms-access, dll, vb6

I have a old program with many years. This is programmed with VB6 and use Access 97 database.
The program worked fine until a few days ago, but the customer has updated something on his computer and now the program gives an error 3041 "Cannot open a database created with a previous version..".
This error is in the line

```
Set BD_Seguro = AreaDeTrabajo.OpenDatabase(PathDatos & "UsuaE.mdb", False)
```

The program use "Microsoft DAO 3.6". I reinstall the program but the problem persists.
What are the necessary libraries for "Microsoft DAO" to work?

Thanks

Comment: Why not roll back that "something" that was updated?

Comment: My customer can't go back anything. He needs his computer as is, and also my program

Comment: What's `AreaDeTrabajo`? Normally, you can create a DB engine using `CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.36")` to make sure you get a JET and not an ACE DB engine, and use that to create a workspace.

Comment: Set AreaDeTrabajo = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

Comment: This is a classic "seek for source of error". A system restore will take your customer 15 minutes, and perhaps another 15 minutes to locate the update causing the error, while it can take days to circumvent this "something". If he isn't familiar with a system restore, ask him to call IT support.

Comment: I know this is unhelpful but....97? .. a 24 year old version...  time to upgrade the app to current baseline? ...may be it will live another 24 yrs....

Comment: you're right Cahaba, but it's a program that still works on many clients, who don't want to change it to more modern versions

Comment: @KarlosGarcia an update probably won't solve the immediate problem, but this kind of fragility in old programs is a good way to start convincing them they need to (meaning, they need to pay to update it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC the file VB6DEDP.ini which comes with VB6 should list most of the dependencies which are relevant for DAO.

This is a map of VB6DEP.ini dependencies that I made using GraphViz a while ago:

[image]

(click it to expand)

Here's the portion which seems to be relevant for DAO360:
[image]

In my experience this is a good starting point for what must be installed on a computer for DAO360 to work.

Given that you are reading an old format MDB you may also need to make sure the MSRD2x...DLL files are also present, as I think these are converters or adapters from version "2" to something later.

Comment: great job @UuDdLrLrSs. I did not know the file VB6DEP.INI. Now I can study specifically what is missing. Although if he pays for a new version better ...